# Removing DEBUG privileges for schema?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a schema with two tables called calculus and dcalculus. I currently have DEBUG privileges enabled for these tables. I'm trying to write a SQL query that removes DEBUG privileges for these tables.

I couldn't find a query that would remove these privileges correctly. I've seen something like 
`REVOKE privileges FROM calculus for example`. Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Oracle:

```
SQL> grant debug on emp to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> revoke debug on emp from mike;

Revoke succeeded.

SQL>
```

Comment: So in the schema. The two tables I have would I just need to say revoke debug on calculus,dcalculus FROM John(Schema) for example

Comment: Nope, you'd revoke it for each table separately, not within the same statement.